# Laravel 5.4 Error when Joining two tables

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

I need to join two tables in laravel model. Here is my query,

```
 $id="1002"; 
 $resultsInCalls =  DB::table('qlog')
    ->select('user_master.fname','user_master.lname','qlog.data2')
    ->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))    // this day

    ->join('qlog', 'qlog.agent', '=', 'user_master.sip_id')
    ->where('agent', '=', $id)   
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('event', '=', 'COMPLETEAGENT')
           ->orWhere('event', '=', 'COMPLETECALLER');
         }) 
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

But I run this query I get following error.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'qlog' (SQL: select `user_master`.`fname`, `user_master`.`lname`, `qlog`.`data2` from `qlog` inner join `qlog` on `qlog`.`agent` = `user_master`.`sip_id` where date(`created`) = 2017-11-29 and `agent` = 1002 and (`event` = COMPLETEAGENT or `event` = COMPLETECALLER) limit 5)
```

I read related questions. But I can't figure it out. How to fix this error.

Comment: You need to join to `user_master`, but you never do this.

Comment: Thanks I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Here I get it done,

```
 $resultsInCalls =  DB::table('qlog')
        ->join('user_master as user_table', 'qlog.agent', '=', 'user_table.sip_id')
        ->select('user_table.fname','user_table.lname','qlog.data2')
        ->whereDate('created', '=', date('Y-m-d'))    // this day
        ->where('agent', '=', $id)   
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('event', '=', 'COMPLETEAGENT')
               ->orWhere('event', '=', 'COMPLETECALLER');
             }) 
        ->take(5)
        ->get();
```